# Upgrading CMS database from 2009 to 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, database, upgrade

We are in the middle of upgrading our system from 2009 to 2013 SP1.
We have already run the upgrade content data store script successfully.

Now we want to upgrade content manager database, which is available as backup on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2).
When we try to run the script via windows powershell as Administrator as follows :

> PS E:\Database\MSSQL> & '.\Upgrade Content Manager database.ps1'

It asks for Database Details and after conformation

> Verify ready Do you really want to upgrade database with specified
>   settings? [Y] Yes  [N] No  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y

It gives following message :

> Database is up to date or has invalid version.
>   Transcript stopped, output file is
>   C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Upgrade Content Manager
>   database_155116030820
>   14.log

Here we are not sure what exactly happened?
It says Database is up to date : but when we see database tables, are not updated as expected.
and Database version is current as per Prerequisite.
Current Microsoft SQL Database server version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)
        Jun 28 2012 08:36:30
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Anybody else faced this issue before?
All suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you upgrading from Tridion 2009 or Tridion 2009 SP1?

Direct upgrade from Tridion 2009 is not supported. You must first upgrade to one of the [versions from which you can upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=2009&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1394353622040&currentQuery=2009&currentScope=) [Login Required]

- SDL Tridion 2013
- SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 (Hotfix Rollup 2)
- SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 (Hotfix Rollup 1)
- SDL Tridion 2011 SP1
- SDL Tridion 2009 SP1

Comment: We are upgrading from `Tridion 2009` version. After reading this, we are planning to upgrade Tridion CMS to `2009 SP1 version` and then to `Tridion 2013 SP1 version`. Please suggest do we need to do the same for `CDS` also. Because we are successfully updated from `2009 CDS` to `2013 SP1 CDS` and able to publish from `Tridion 2009 CMS`.

Comment: Both the CM and CD have the same "versions from which you can upgrade".  Therefore, I would recommend also following the same life cycle upgrading CD, of first updating to an upgradable version, then upgrading to 2013 SP1. 

Although publishing may have worked, you could still be missing schema changes introduced in 2009 SP1 which have not yet made themselves known to you.

Either perform the upgrades back to back jumping straight to 2013 SP1, or followed a staged upgrade, once on a supported version. http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/upgrading-to-sdl-tridion-2013-the-staged-upgrade/

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should see that the table tds_db_info is updated with the cms version, perhaps your version is already set to 7.1.0 (at a guess) - if this value is checked at the start of the upgrade, the upgrade won't process.

Are you sure that the upgrade wasn't successful, have you tried to use the DB with your updated GUI.

Comment: We checked the table: tds_db_info. It is showing 2009 version only. It is not updated.